# G++ compilation erro for openssl API

Tags: c++, openssl

I have encountered problem while compiling the openssl function to get the expiry date from public certificate using G++ compiler.

The error's are,

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘not’ token
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Compilation procedure,

```
g++  main.c -o test -I /usr/include/openssl/ -lcrypto -lssl
```

All the header files are included.

Code below I have compiled,

```
 main ()
{
        X509 *x;

        int n=0;

        unsigned char *not;            //expected unqualified-id before ‘not’ token ,expected initializer before ‘not’ token
        BIO *out;
        FILE *fp=fopen("/home/public.cer", "r");

        x = X509_new();
        x = PEM_read_X509(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        fclose(fp);

        out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        ASN1_TIME_print(out, X509_get_notAfter(x));//expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
        n = BIO_get_mem_data(out, &not);
        expiryStr = (char *) malloc (n+1);
        expiryStr[n] = '\0';
        memcpy(expiryStr, not, n);//expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
    printf("Expiry Date====================%s\n",expiryStr);
        BIO_free(out);

        X509_free(x);        
}
```

Please help me resolving this error.

Answer (score 3):

"not" is a keyword in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword. You'll have to rename the variable.

Comment: Thank you mr.Flanagan. I am able to compile now